How i can re-execute StateFlow in ViewModel Android? I have use case where i needs to do refresh of data
I am trying re-execute StateFlow in ViewModel (refresh something, new API request...), but it not work. This is my simple example about counter:
Viewmodel
class CounterViewModel(
    private val counterRepository: CounterRepository = CounterRepository(),
) : ViewModel() {
    val count: StateFlow<Int> = counterRepository.getCountStream()
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000L),
            initialValue = 0
        )

    fun restartCounter() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            count.launchIn(this)
        }
    }
}

Data
class CounterRepository {
    fun getCountStream(): Flow<Int> = flow {
        var count = 0
        while (true) {
            emit(count)
            delay(1_000L)
            count++
        }
    }
}


Have you read this?

That's smelly, I don't really see a valid use case for that. StateFlows cannot be restarted like this, you would need to work around that. But if you insist:

You could make var count = 0 a property in CounterRepository and then also add this function that you can call from the view model:
fun reset() {
    count = 0
}


OR you can change you view model so the StatFlow is based on a toggle that you can use to restart the underlying flow (i.e. flatmap to getCountStream() which returns a new underlying flow starting from 0):
private val resetFlowToggle = MutableStateFlow(false)

val count: StateFlow<Int> = resetFlowToggle
    .flatMapLatest { counterRepository.getCountStream() }
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = 0,
    )

fun restartCounter() {
    resetFlowToggle.update { !it }
}



